DBT 1.8 Nvarchar missing length with SQL Server
I was in the process of developing a couple unit tests using DBT and was getting some interesting results. I was testing some complex logic that involved comparing a nvarchar(315) column to some other values but it showing the expected value and actual values mismatching when they should not.
I took a closer look at the compiled unit test code and found that when it tries to cast the the input values for the nvarchar columns it does not include the length as it would for a varchar column. example below
select 
    try_cast(5 as varchar(50)) as PrimaryKey, try_cast('TestValueTestValueTestValueTestValueTestValue' as nvarchar) as Column1
union all
    try_cast(6 as varchar(50)) as PrimaryKey, try_cast('TestValue' as nvarchar) as Column1

If I run the select code it will truncate the column1 down to 30 characters.
I'm running the following versions
dbt-core 1.8.7
dbt-extracto 0.5.1
dbt-fabric 1.8.7
dbt-semantic-interfaces 0.5.1
dbt-sqlserver 1.8.4
I've ran into other issues around dbt losing the length of nvarchar columns but I cant remember them off the top of my head.
Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it.
I confirmed that the data types are specified in the yaml files. Also confirmed that that the data type in the database is nvarchar(315). I would expect that when compiling the unit tests the data type and length of the column would match what the referenced model uses.
